# Fuse values from first column, when the values from second column is the same in different files in awk or bash by using awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I have two files, which consists of two columns. In each file in the first column you have a MGD_number and in the second column you have SOL_number.
In File1 you have MGD226-MGD450
In File2 you have MGD451-MGD675
I want to make a new file in which base on the same SOL_number from a different file you will fuse value of MGD from the one first from the second file (and put in $2) by using awk or in bash.
For example
MGD226 SOL17 in file1 and MGD456 SOL81 in file2 -> MGD226 MGD456 in file3
This is prohibited:
MGD251 SOL17 in file1 and MGD378 SOL81 in file1 (the same file!) -> MGD251 MGD378 in file3

These are part of my two files

File1 input

```
MGD278 SOL51
MGD341 SOL51
MGD412 SOL78
MGD312 SOL78
```

File2 input

```
MGD489 SOL51
MGD572 SOL51
MGD613 SOL78
MGD684 SOL16
```

Expected output File3

```
MGD278 MGD489
MGD278 MGD572
MGD341 MGD489
MGD341 MGD572
MGD412 MGD613
MGD312 MGD613
```

Edit: I get an error on some data

I tried

`join -j 2 file1 file2 | awk '{print $2, $3}' > file3`

but its not working on some of my data, for example

file1

```
MGD226 SOL4454
MGD226 SOL9311
MGD226 SOL7369
MGD226 SOL1813
MGD227 SOL1696
```

file2

```
MGD451 SOL4198
MGD451 SOL1429
MGD452 SOL4803
MGD452 SOL1696
MGD452 SOL7369
```

expected output

```
MGD226  MGD452
MGD227  MGD452
```

I get an error

```
join: file2:4: not sorted: MGD452 SOL1696
join: file1:3: not sorted: MGD226 SOL7369
join: input is not sorted
```

I tried sort it like
`sort -k 1 -n` or `sort -k 2 -n`
, but I get wrong output

Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: You should be able to do this with the `join` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run

```
join -j 2 file1 file2 | awk '{print $2, $3}' > file3
```

on the files `file1` and `file2` as above, I get

```
MGD278 MGD489
MGD278 MGD572
MGD341 MGD489
MGD341 MGD572
MGD412 MGD613
MGD312 MGD613
```

in `file3`, which is what you want, assuming that your input files are sorted on the second field. If that is not the case, you will first have to sort these.

```
sort -k 2 file1 > file1.sorted
sort -k 2 file2 > file2.sorted
join -j 2 file1.sorted file2.sorted | awk '{print $2, $3}' > file3
rm file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

Comment: It's working thanks, but still on some data I get an error. Do you know why? (I edited my post in which I described my problem.

Comment: The command `join` doesn't work when the input files are not sorted on the key, which is the second field in this case. I will edit my answer to take the case of unsorted files in account.